# error in mutex initialization with pthread

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pthreads, mutex

Hi guys i'm trying to start this mutex but the code doesn't work:

```
typedef struct{
        int somma;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;  // TODO completare con le variabili per la sincronizzazione tra i thread
}Buffer;


typedef struct {
        int id;
        Buffer* b;
} parametri;
```

in the main i do :

```
parametri * p=malloc(sizeof(parametri));
        init_buffer(p->b);
```

and i call this function:

```
void init_buffer(Buffer* a){
       pthread_mutex_init(&a->mutex,NULL);      //TODO inizializzazione del buffer

        printf("[SERVER] -INIT...\n");
}
```

but the code stop work and doesn't print the [SERVER]INIT so i think it's a problem of mutex init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `p->b` in `main` is *uninitialized*.  You then pass that uninitialized pointer to `init_buffer` and attempt to dereference it.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can fix this by either allocating space for `b`:

```
parametri *p=malloc(sizeof(parametri));
p->b = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
```

Or changing the struct definition to use an instance of `Buffer` instead of a pointer:

```
typedef struct {
        int id;
        Buffer b;
} parametri;
```